# ImportError: cannot import name 'deprecated' from 'gensim.utils

Tags: python, scipy, deprecated, gensim, summarize

while importing the below lines Jupyter compiler result in an error.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'deprecated' from 'gensim.utils
```

```
from gensim.summarization.summarizer import summarize
from gensim.summarization import keywords**
```

Error as follows:

```
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\gensim\summarization\summarizer.py in <module>
     54 
     55 import logging
---> 56 from gensim.utils import deprecated
     57 from gensim.summarization.pagerank_weighted import pagerank_weighted as _pagerank
     58 from gensim.summarization.textcleaner import clean_text_by_sentences as _clean_text_by_sentences

ImportError: cannot import name 'deprecated' from 'gensim.utils' (C:\Users\PavanKumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py)
```

Comment: line `from gensim.utils import deprecated` works with `Python 3.8` but `gensim` may not be ready to work with `Python 3.9` so better use little older Python which may have all modules. Newest versions sometimes may have to wait for modules created specially for newest Python. OR check if there is newer version  of `gensim` which may already work with `Python 3.9`

Comment: on [gensims page](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) you can see `tested with versions 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8.` So it wasn't tested with `3.9` and it may not work with this version. And you  use `3.9`

Comment: line `from gensim.utils import deprecated` works for me with `Python 3.9` and `gensims 4.0.1`

Comment: but they removed `gensim.summarization` from `4.0.1` so better keep version `3.8.3`

Answer (score 0):

The `summarization` code was removed from Gensim 4.0. See:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4#12-removed-gensimsummarization

> ##### 12. Removed `gensim.summarization`
>
> Despite its general-sounding name, the module will not satisfy the
> majority of use cases in production and is likely to waste people's
> time. See [this Github
> ticket](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2592) for
> more motivation behind this.

If you need it, you could try:

- installing the older gensim version; or…
- copy the source code out to your own local module

However, I expect you'd likely be disappointed by its inflexibility and how little it can do. It's *only* extractive summarization - choosing a few key sentences from those that already exist – which only gives impressive results when the source text was already well-written in an expository style mixing high-level summaries with details. And its method of analyzing/ranking words is very crude & hard-to-customize.